# KENDO UI COMBO BOX multiple rows for one element

Tags: jquery, json, combobox, kendo-ui

i have a kendo combobox being populated by a ajax call.. the problem is when the list just have one element..

if i have this in the getNifs (JSON)
"A08000143"
"A08000142"
the combobox will be populated properly..

if i just have: `"A08000143"`

the combo will be populated like this:

```
"A"
"0"
"8"
"0"
"0"
```

and so on..

This is my jquery VIEW

```
             $("#divNIF").kendoComboBox({
                filter: "contains",
                placeholder: "Select Nif...",
                dataBound: onDataBound,
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "@Url.Action("GetNifs", "Movimientos")",
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is the GETNif's function

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetNifs()
    {
        List <string> aux_2 = getfromrepository..

        if (cliente.test)
        {
            return Json(aux_2.GetNIFs().First(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(cliente.NIF, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the JSON that you receive? I mean, if you open the URL in your browser what is exactly what you are receiving?

Comment: "A08000143" only these

Comment: The JSON needs to be an array. If you return a string what the system gets is an array of chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the returned value needs to be an array despite it might take one single element.

If you return a `string` then this is converted to an `array` of `char` and you get what you are seeing.

If you cannot change what the controlled returns, you might do the *trick* in the `DataSource` definition and check if the value is a `string´ convert it to an`array`with one single`string`. Something like:

```
$("#divNIF").kendoComboBox({
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Select Nif...",
    dataBound: onDataBound,
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "@Url.Action("GetNifs", "Movimientos")",
            }
        },
        schema: {
            parse: function(d) {
                if (typeof d === "string") {
                    return [d];
                } else {
                    return d;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Where I've added a `parse` function that check that the received parameter is a `string` and if so returns the original data inside an `[ ... ]`.

Check the difference between one and the other behavior in the following example : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/cQEH9/

Comment: i didn't test your code, i did the "parse" in the controller, but the problem was well detected! tks